# What is reverse action for pack('V') in PHP?

Tags: php, pack

I saw a code like this:

```
$len = strlen($str1);
$str = pack('V', $len) . $str1 . $str2;
```

What will be the code for doing the reverse thing?

As far, as I understand, the first step would be:

```
$len = substr($str, 0, 4);
$str = substr($str, 4);
```

But what is next?

```
$len = unpack(???);
$str1 = substr($str, 0, $len);
$str2 = substr($str, $len);
```

I don't quite understand how am I supposed to convert binary `$len` back to... binary integer? I would use a simple typecast or memory copy in the usual languages, but I am new to PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a case of removing the extra string added here

`$str = pack('V', $len) . $str1 . $str2;`

and unpacking the rest.

Example:

```
// your code
$len = strlen($str1);
$str = pack('V', $len) . $str1 . $str2;

// unpacking
$length_of_packed_string = strlen($str) - strlen($str1 . $str2);
$unpacked = unpack('V', substr($str, 0, $length_of_packed_string));

print_r($unpacked);
```

Note that this returns an array, with your value at index 1 (the only index) - so `$unpacked[1]`. See the notes section on the [unpack manpage](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) for more info on why.

https://3v4l.org/dgWR9

Comment: The pack/unpack code are unrelated (e.g. located in different places), so no `$str1` on the unpacking side. Why are you calculating `$length_of_packed_string`? Isn't it just `4`?

Comment: @АлександрКулагин only for that specific format. If it's not variable, you can just do `$len = unpack('V', substr($str, 0, 4));`. But there's not going to be a way to work out what $str1 or $str2 are, as they're just concatenated. A separator would help there

Comment: Perhaps, I am missing something, but isn't that what `$len` is for? It says that length `$str1` is.